# String formatting - tuple index out of range

Tags: python, string, formatting

I'm trying to put variables into long string but it raises error. I've tried %s notation and now I'm trying to put there `.format()` notation but it doesn't work either.

Could you tell me what is the problem? Is it because the string is on multiple lines?

```
    num = 5
    r=requests.post("http://www.quoka.de/kleinanzeigen/nachhilfe/cat_0_ct_0_page_'{0}'.html".format(str(num)), headers=mLib.firebug_headers_to_dict("""POST /kleinanzeigen/nachhilfe/cat_0_ct_0_page_'{1}'.html HTTP/1.1
    Host: www.quoka.de
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0
    Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
    Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
    Referer: http://www.quoka.de/kleinanzeigen/nachhilfe/cat_0_ct_0_page_'{2}'.html
    Cookie: QSESSID=cs9djh8q8c6mjgsme85s4mf7iq24pqrthag630ar6po9fp078e20; PARTNER=VIEW%02quoka%01COOKIEBEGIN%021438270171; QUUHS=QPV%027%01QABAFS%02A%01ARYSEARCHODER%02%7B%22search1%22%3A%22nachhilfe%22%7D; __utma=195481459.415565446.1438270093.1438270093.1438270093.1; __utmb=195481459.22.8.1438270093; __utmc=195481459; __utmz=195481459.1438270093.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); __utmt=1; __utmt_t2=1; POPUPCHECK=1438356493224; axd=100086901728180087; __gads=ID=92bfc541911a1c81:T=1438270098:S=ALNI_MYuEdhQnu7sWAfK-fyKf1Ej93_9KA; crtg_rta=; OX_sd=5; OX_plg=wmp|pm; rsi_segs=L11278_10123|L11278_10571|L11278_11639|F12351_10001|F12351_0; PURESADSCL=done
    Connection: keep-alive
    """.format(str(num),str(num-1))))
```

ERROR:

```
 """.format(str(num),str(num-1))))
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Comment: Well, what **are** you expecting to end up in `{2}`? The numbering should start over when you reach the multiline string, which is completely separate from the URL string.

Answer (score 0):

Your format string starts numbering at 1, not 0. You only provide 2 values for slots 0 and 1, but your template expects parameters numbered 1 and 2.

Note that you have *two separate strings* here. The first string uses `{0}`, the second uses `{1}` and `{2}`. Renumber those to `{0}` and `{1}` instead.

To reiterate, the first string is fine:

```
"http://www.quoka.de/kleinanzeigen/nachhilfe/cat_0_ct_0_page_'{0}'.html".format(str(num))
```

but you have to restart the numbering in the second string. In that string you have

```
POST /kleinanzeigen/nachhilfe/cat_0_ct_0_page_'{1}'.html HTTP/1.1
```

and

```
Referer: http://www.quoka.de/kleinanzeigen/nachhilfe/cat_0_ct_0_page_'{2}'.html
```

Simply use

```
POST /kleinanzeigen/nachhilfe/cat_0_ct_0_page_'{0}'.html HTTP/1.1
```

and

```
Referer: http://www.quoka.de/kleinanzeigen/nachhilfe/cat_0_ct_0_page_'{1}'.html
```

Note that those `'..'` single quotes are *part of the string you are producing*. I just tested the site and the URLs there do not use those quotes. You should probably remove them. You also don't have to call `str()` on everything, the template takes care of that for you:

```
num = 5
r = requests.post(
    "http://www.quoka.de/kleinanzeigen/nachhilfe/cat_0_ct_0_page_{0}.html".format(num),
    headers=mLib.firebug_headers_to_dict("""\
POST /kleinanzeigen/nachhilfe/cat_0_ct_0_page_{0}.html HTTP/1.1
Host: www.quoka.de
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://www.quoka.de/kleinanzeigen/nachhilfe/cat_0_ct_0_page_{1}.html
Cookie: QSESSID=cs9djh8q8c6mjgsme85s4mf7iq24pqrthag630ar6po9fp078e20; PARTNER=VIEW%02quoka%01COOKIEBEGIN%021438270171; QUUHS=QPV%027%01QABAFS%02A%01ARYSEARCHODER%02%7B%22search1%22%3A%22nachhilfe%22%7D; __utma=195481459.415565446.1438270093.1438270093.1438270093.1; __utmb=195481459.22.8.1438270093; __utmc=195481459; __utmz=195481459.1438270093.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); __utmt=1; __utmt_t2=1; POPUPCHECK=1438356493224; axd=100086901728180087; __gads=ID=92bfc541911a1c81:T=1438270098:S=ALNI_MYuEdhQnu7sWAfK-fyKf1Ej93_9KA; crtg_rta=; OX_sd=5; OX_plg=wmp|pm; rsi_segs=L11278_10123|L11278_10571|L11278_11639|F12351_10001|F12351_0; PURESADSCL=done
Connection: keep-alive
""".format(num, num - 1)
    ))
```

Furthermore, I strongly doubt you need to include the `POST <path> HTTP/1.1`line at all. The `Host`, `Accept-Encoding` and `Connection` headers will be taken care of by `requests`, and if you were to use a `Session()` object, so will the cookies. Try not to set all those headers explicitly. Setting the headers as a dictionary is perhaps more readable:

```
session = requests.Session()
url = 'http://www.quoka.de/kleinanzeigen/nachhilfe/cat_0_ct_0_page_{0}.html'
num = 5
r = session.post(
    url.format(num),
    headers={
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0',
        'Referer': url.format(num - 1),
    }
)
```

Last but not least, are you sure you need to perform a `POST` here? You are not posting anything, and a GET works just fine too.

Comment: No I'm not, there are 2 separated texts. The first {0} is in the first text so it is formatting there.

Comment: @Milan: that is a *separate string*.

Answer (score 0):

In the second multi-line string, you are giving indexes as - `{1}` and `{2}` at -

```
_page_'{1}'.html
```

and

```
_0_page_'{2}'.html
```

But you are only giving two variables as argument for the `format()` function.

That is why when format function tries to access variable at `{2}` (which is the third argument, as its 0 indexed) it gets error.

You should define them as `{0}` and `{1}` .

Example -

```
r=requests.post("http://www.quoka.de/kleinanzeigen/nachhilfe/cat_0_ct_0_page_'{0}'.html".format(str(num)), headers=mLib.firebug_headers_to_dict("""POST /kleinanzeigen/nachhilfe/cat_0_ct_0_page_'{0}'.html HTTP/1.1
    Host: www.quoka.de
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0
    Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
    Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
    Referer: http://www.quoka.de/kleinanzeigen/nachhilfe/cat_0_ct_0_page_'{1}'.html
    Cookie: QSESSID=cs9djh8q8c6mjgsme85s4mf7iq24pqrthag630ar6po9fp078e20; PARTNER=VIEW%02quoka%01COOKIEBEGIN%021438270171; QUUHS=QPV%027%01QABAFS%02A%01ARYSEARCHODER%02%7B%22search1%22%3A%22nachhilfe%22%7D; __utma=195481459.415565446.1438270093.1438270093.1438270093.1; __utmb=195481459.22.8.1438270093; __utmc=195481459; __utmz=195481459.1438270093.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); __utmt=1; __utmt_t2=1; POPUPCHECK=1438356493224; axd=100086901728180087; __gads=ID=92bfc541911a1c81:T=1438270098:S=ALNI_MYuEdhQnu7sWAfK-fyKf1Ej93_9KA; crtg_rta=; OX_sd=5; OX_plg=wmp|pm; rsi_segs=L11278_10123|L11278_10571|L11278_11639|F12351_10001|F12351_0; PURESADSCL=done
    Connection: keep-alive
    """.format(str(num),str(num-1))))
```